# meteorjs packages not visible

Tags: meteor, package

I'm new to meteor. I just created an app and install bootstrap and iron-router via mrt.
When I look at the file structure, I can see iron-router but not bootstrap (I don't see all the other pre-installed packages either).

When I run the app, everything works fine though. But I need to see these packages to understand what's happening.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of packages in Meteor projects. 'official' packages and unsupported community packages (from atmospherejs.com)

The `mrt` package manager wasn't built by the Meteor Core development team (as of v0.8.1). The packages from atmosphere will be installed in `/packages`

The other packages which are officially part of Meteor are not visible here but they are used from `~/.meteor/packages`. Alternatively you can browse the source of them here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages.

Eventually meteorite and meteor will be merged. Even though Meteorite installs these community packages for you, it looks like when it is folded into meteor it will remain this way (installing into /packages).

So in short, the 'official' packages aren't installed in /packages because they are available in all meteor distributions, whereas the unsupported ones from atmosphere need to be downloaded for the project in question into /packages.